# C# Regex expression for custom date format validation

Tags: c#, regex

I have following string of date & I am building one regex for it, however not sure where to start.

- 20160701 08:05:00.063191 +0100s
- 20180507 12:11:38.805300 +0100
- 20180507 15:14:03.408020 +0000
- 00000000 00:00:00.000000 +0000

This is for first part what I have build so far
^\d{4}((0\d)|(1[012]))(([012]\d)|3[01])$

Comment: Why use Regex?  Just use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`

Comment: Need to add validation at model level in mvc app as data annotation

Comment: If you have built something, you apparently have an idea of where to start, so what's the real issue?

Comment: Creating a regex to validate a date is going to be a huge mess.  You have to include conditions for the number of days in certain months and handle leap years.  You'll be better off using a validation that doesn't require regex.